# Neo4j all the ways to run a `MATCH`

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to fill in my understanding of the fundamentals of neo4j (version 3.4).

I believe that all of the following produce the same results -- ie **they are different syntax for doing exactly the same thing**:

```
MATCH (ee {name: "Emil"}) RETURN ee;
MATCH (ee) WHERE ee.name = "Emil" RETURN ee;
MATCH (ee:Person {name: "Emil"}) RETURN ee;
MATCH (ee:Person) WHERE ee.name = "Emil" RETURN ee;
MATCH (ee:Person) WHERE (ee).name = "Emil" RETURN ee;
```

I actually have several questions:

- Among this list is there a "best" way of doing a `Node` `MATCH`? Obviously using a `:Label` makes it more efficient, but the effect of `WHERE` vs prop maps is mysterious.
- Are any of these out-right incorrect? That is to say that although they work, it's kind of unintended or a particularly bad pattern.
- Are there additional ways of making a `MATCH` operation, further to this list? I'm curious for an exhaustive list (wrong or right).

Answer (score 1):

1. Your clauses are NOT all the same.

   The first group of (2) `MATCH` clauses DO NOT require the `Person` label for matched nodes. But the second group of (3) clauses DO require the `Person` label.
2. Putting a label (or many labels, as appropriate) on a node is generally a good idea, as matching on a label is a quick way to filter your nodes when performing a `MATCH`. And labels also aid in data model understandability. In addition, a label is required if you wanted to [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) a node property.

   But whether or not you *should* specify a label (or several) on a specific  a `MATCH` clause depends on the amount of filtering you are trying to do. Omitting all labels from a `MATCH` would be perfectly appropriate if at that point in your query you really wanted to match nodes with any label (or even no labels).

Comment: Hi @cybersam they may not be the same but they do all "work" -- that's the point. What made me mention `:Label` is because of having read the discussion about indexing here: https://neo4j.com/blog/dark-side-neo4j-worst-practices/, but again, it still "works", even if it's crap.  ... Do you know any others that work?

Comment: Your question stated incorrectly that they do "exactly the same thing", so I was correcting that. I'm not sure what you are now asking...

Answer (score 1):

For an ***exhaustive list***, you might include:

```
MATCH (ee) WHERE ee.name in ["Emil"] RETURN ee
```

This is not particularly helpful with a single item, but you can have multiple comma delimited items in a list or a collection. For example,

```
match (n:order{item:'widget'}) 
with collect(distinct n.customer_id) as customerCollection
match (c:Customers) where c.customer_id in [customerCollection]
return c.Name, c.City
```